# Working with links in Django

Tags: html, django

I am working in a small blog application using Django. Sorry if the question is obvious, but I am a newbie. Actually it is my third since I started an online course. I have the following Queryset:

```
def all(request):
    allTiles = Post.objects.values('title')
    allPosts = Post.objects.all()[:3]
    context = {'Posts': allPosts,"Titles":allTiles}
    template = "home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

and the follwing html code:

```
<ol class="list-unstyled">

            {% for singleTile in Titles %}
            <li><a href="#">{{singleTile.title}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ol>
```

As you can see every title creates an link. Lets assume a person decides to read one of the posts. How can I use the title name and send a request back to the database to get the content of the post.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the `id` or `slug` field for such task.

But if you surely want to use the `title` as the GET parameter then apply  the [urlencode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) filter to the field's value:

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' %}?title={{ singleTile.title|urlencode }}">
    {{ singleTile.title }}
</a>
```

And the view will be something like this:

```
def post_detail(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, title=request.GET.get('title'))
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

**UPDATE**: If you decide to go with the `id`/`slug` option then you can use the generic [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView):

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' singleTile.id %}">
    {{ singleTile.title }}
</a
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from app.models import Post

url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(model=Post),
                            name='post_detail')
```

Comment: Just a quick question: what does post after r'^ means?

Comment: This is an base url to all your posts.  So they be `yoursite.com/post/1/`, `yoursite.com/post/2/` and so on.  You can omit this string: `r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$'` so url will be: `yoursite.com/1/`...  Read the URL dispatcher docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#example

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure url first like

`<a href="#">{% url 'app.views.post_id' singleTile.id %}</a></li>`

In your urls

```
url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', views.by_id, name='post_id'),
```

And in your views

```
def post_id(request, post_id):
   allTiles = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
   return render(request, template, context)
```